# Got WARN ipc.Client: interrupted waiting to send params to server when copying files to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I write a perl script, in which `copyFromLocal` is called to upload files. When it runs, a  `WARN ipc.Client: interrupted waiting to send params to server` happens. I check all the files on HDFS just uploaded. It seems that they were all copied successfully.

Any one knows what does that warning means ? 
Complete warning information

```
12/10/23 11:41:07 WARN ipc.Client: interrupted waiting to send params to server
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1279)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:218)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.sendParam(Client.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1080)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:226)
        at $Proxy5.renewLease(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
        at $Proxy5.renewLease(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$LeaseChecker.renew(DFSClient.java:1147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$LeaseChecker.run(DFSClient.java:1159)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
12/10/23 11:41:07 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Problem renewing lease for DFSClient_-1491276805
java.io.IOException: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1086)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:226)
        at $Proxy5.renewLease(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
        at $Proxy5.renewLease(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$LeaseChecker.renew(DFSClient.java:1147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$LeaseChecker.run(DFSClient.java:1159)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1279)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:218)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.sendParam(Client.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1080)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: From the warning message, I see problem occur in renewing lease when `copyFromLocal`. Some one told me the lease is get from `namenode`, and it will provide access to visit `datanode`.  But I'm puzzled why all these files are successfully uploaded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my own research on this problem, it appears to be related to this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6762

It looks like various fixes have been tried but nothing that actually solves the problem satisfactorily. Regardless, it is just a warning, and in every case of this warning I have investigated, the desired operation did actually succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Even the warning happens, everything is OK. So I ignored the warning.